# Can't get MKTileOverlay to support 1024 x 1024 sized tiles...

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, mapkit, mktileoverlay

if I set the tileSize property of MKTileOverlay to tileSize=CGSizeMake(1024, 1024).
the mapViewer shows my tiles all over the view with gaps and in the wrong order.
I have produced tiles that are in the dimension 1024 x 1024.

zoom level 1 has 4 png tiles,
zoom level 2 has 16 png tiles,
zoom level 3 has 64 png tiles

if I set MKTileOverlay.tileSize=CGSizeMake(256, 256) and provide 256x256 tiles 
everything works fine?

what could be the problem?